# Use dictionary as lookup table

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, operating-system, jinja2

I have a jinja template that I want to pass a value into (an identifier for a country). The format of the data is a two letter country code (for example `"PL"` for Poland).

Through the template, I need to pass the corresponding *flag* as an output, but the flag is saved in the app folder structure, so i need to get the path to the image.

My problem: I could not figure out a way to use `os.path` in jinja, so now im trying to solve it by creating a dictionary that matches country string and relative path like this:

```
countries = {"PL" : "countries/flags/poland.png"}
```

where the system path to the app folder gets added afterwards in Python through `os.path`.

My question: How can i use the country string I am getting to automate transformation into the path format of the country? Something like:

```
for data in countries:
    if data in countries.keys:
        return countries.value
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `data` is a country code (like `"PL"` for example):

```
def get_path(data):
    return countries.get(data)
```

The `get()` method checks if the dictionary has the key, and if so returns the corresponding value, otherwise it returns `None`.

If you want a default value other than `None` when the key is not present you can specify it as second argument, like this:

```
def get_path(data):
    return countries.get(data, "default/path/x/y/z")
```